# Why is my JQuery function POSTing a null JSON string to my controller?

Tags: c#, jquery

When my JQuery function executes, I'm writing the global variable out to the console to make sure that there's something in it.  There is: 24 JSON objects.

Yet, when the function tries to POST this global variable back to the server, the method is getting a null JSON object instead of the 24 items that I'm looking for.

Here's the JQuery function:

```
$("#dismissBtn").on('click', function() 
{
    console.log(attendeeClassesGlobal);
    alert("Check the console");
    // Dismiss button has been clicked, so let's deal
    // with the classes for this attendee
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Class/DismissAttendeeFromAllClasses/",
        type: "POST",
        data: { attendeeClassesGlobal, __RequestVerificationToken: $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val() },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (attendeeClasses) {

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            if (xhr.responseText !== "") {
                alertify.alert(xhr.responseText);
                alertify.error(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }

    });
});
```

I've got a breakpoint set in the controller's method that this function is calling.  When I check the incoming JSON parameter, it's null. What I can't understand is why the global variable has 24 objects in it inside the JQuery function, but null is being passed. Here's my C# method that handles the POST:

```
public ActionResult DismissAttendeeFromAllClasses(string json)
{
    if (!Employee.CurrentUser.CanEditAttendees)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("You are not authorized to perform this action");
    }

    var attendeeClasses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<AttendeeClassViewModel>>(json);

    foreach (var attendeeClass in attendeeClasses)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(attendeeClass);
    }

    return this.Json(null);
}
```

So, I'm guessing the way I'm sending the JSON obect to the POST handler is wrong.  I'm hoping someone can point out what I'm doing wrong here.

EDIT: Thank you, everyone, for your suggestions.  I've tried them all to no avail.  Just for reference, this is what my the global variable looks like when I log it to the console in dev tools. There are 24 objects within this array:

[image: Console output]

I can't see anything wrong with it, but maybe I'm missing something?

EDIT#2: I forgot to mention that even the JSON.stringify didn't help.  While it made my JSON objects look nice in the console, they never make it to my controller method because the string `json` is always null instead of filled with my 24 JSON objects that I'm expecting.

EDIT#3: It appears that I didn't have matching parameter names.  Being new to ajax/mvc POSTing, I wasn't aware of this requirement.  This resolved my issue.  Thanks to all that offered advice!

Comment: Try running your data payload through JSON.stringify, ie data: { JSON.stringify(attendeeClassesGlobal), __RequestVerificationToken: $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val() },

Comment: May be an issue with your JSON format. Try giving `attendeeClassesGlobal` a property name like you do with `__RequestVerificationToken:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter name in the JQuery post function doesn't match the parameter name in the controller method. Once this was fixed, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't define the parameter in your controller as an object and let the serializer maps the object instead of sending a string?

```
public ActionResult DismissAttendeeFromAllClasses(IEnumerable<MyViewModel> json)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Edit:

As you are sending a collection, you should update your controller accordingly.

Also include `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` in the request